# Replace DELETE for UPDATE with a trigger on SQLite

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Is it possible in SQLite to make an update instead of a delete within a trigger ?
I.e, I got these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE author (authorid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, temporal NUMERIC);
CREATE TABLE comment (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text TEXT, authorid INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(authorid) REFERENCES author(authorid));
```

When a deletion of an author is attempted and there's any comment referencing that author i want to update the "temporal" field and abort deletion.

I've tested different approaches with triggers but i have not found a way to do the two things, make the update and abort the delete. I can abort the delete (though in this case it's not necessary as it is enforced by the foreign key constraint) or make the update (though the delete will remove the record, so the update has no effect)

Comment: Have a look at instead of triggers.

Comment: I've looked at them, but they can only be applied to views, not tables.

Answer (score 0):

Aborting the deletion is possible only with using `RAISE` to generate an error, but this would have the consequence that any `UPDATE` gets rolled back.

You could make `author` a view and create several `INSTEAD OF` triggers that pass through most actions to the base table.
However, it would be much easier to handler the `temporal` logic in your application.